# Switch between tabs - Selenium - Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda

Need your guidence please
I try to create a Lambda function that run Selenium.

Created the nessecery layers (all the packages and etc) and upload them to the Lambda.
Write the code, locally and on the lambda.

The problem is that:
In my scripts I query web page that has button that open a new tab, and when I run the code in a headless mode using Lambda, I cant switch between the tabs.
Anyone Encounter this issue?

The version are:

1. headless-chromium-v1.0.0.55
2. chrome-driverV2.43

Appriciate any help.
Thanks!

explain in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just loop through the tabs, and use the code below

read more [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/)

```py
   # Store the ID of the original window
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle
    
    # Loop through until we find a new window handle
    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break
```

### Update

if the anchor link is like this `<a href="https://example.com/">click me</a>` then when clicked it will open in the current tab/window

but if its `<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">click me</a>` then when clicked it will open in a new tab

look at the `target` attribute

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|        Value       | Description                                                                     |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|        _blank      | Opens the linked document in a new window or tab                                |
|        _self       | Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default) |
|       _parent      | Opens the linked document in the parent frame                                   |
|       _top         | Opens the linked document in the full body of the window                        |
|       framename    | Opens the linked document in the named iframe                                   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Table from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: Hey Sorry again
I test this code again:

   # Store the ID of the original window
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle
    
    # Loop through until we find a new window handle
    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break

It seems like it doesn't switch to the new tab, I try to print the title and I see that it's not changing to the new one
Any idea how to troubleshoot it?
Locally it's working, but only on Lambda its making me this kind of issue

Comment: I can see that after I clicked the button that was supposed to open up a new tab and  then print the count of the tabs, it still remain at 1
The problem is that the click works locally and performs the switching.
Furthermore, I wrap the "Click" in Try and Except in order to try to catch some errors, but no error was printing. 
Thanks again!

Comment: additionally, I click on a different link on the page, that is supposed to open a new tab, and then count the number of the tabs that open, and it's still 1.
What it can be? I create a screenshot of this action and seems like it's pressing the button but nothing happened..

Comment: @mit a link will only open in a new tab if the anchor link's target value is set to `_blank` else it will open in the same tab

Comment: Can you give me an example?
In the "normal" behavior (using my local computer) I run the same code that I run in Lambda..
that's way it doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: @mit see my update in my answer

Comment: Thanks
It's valid for buttons as well?
I click on a button, not on a link

Comment: @mit buttons are usually linked with javascript via the onclick event, unless you are using a `<button type="submit">click me</button>`, this button when in a form element, will submit the form when clicked.

Comment: Hey, Dean thanks so much for the help.
I found out that the versions I use, are not opening a new tab while using Lambda.
I created a new docker image for ECR with all the necessary requirements and deploy it and now everything is working.
Thanks so much for the help and your time!

Comment: @mit you're welcome, also thanks for posting an update on your issue. good luck with future projects